# Python web server show data

Tags: python

I am a complete rookie in Python and need help to show some data as a web server.
The python code below grabs data from a GPS module and prints the result. I would like the data presented on a web page.
I am using a Raspberry Pi and Python IDE 3

Thank you in advance

[Link to the  code site](http://www.electronicwings.com/raspberry-pi/gps-module-interfacing-with-raspberry-pi)

```
import serial               #import serial pacakge
from time import sleep
import webbrowser           #import package for opening link in browser
import sys                  #import system package

def GPS_Info():
global NMEA_buff
global lat_in_degrees
global long_in_degrees
nmea_time = []
nmea_latitude = []
nmea_longitude = []
nmea_time = NMEA_buff[0]                    #extract time from GPGGA string
nmea_latitude = NMEA_buff[1]                #extract latitude from GPGGA string
nmea_longitude = NMEA_buff[3]               #extract longitude from GPGGA string

print("NMEA Time: ", nmea_time,'\n')
print ("NMEA Latitude:", nmea_latitude,"NMEA Longitude:", nmea_longitude,'\n')

lat = float(nmea_latitude)                  #convert string into float for calculation
longi = float(nmea_longitude)               #convertr string into float for calculation

lat_in_degrees = convert_to_degrees(lat)    #get latitude in degree decimal format
long_in_degrees = convert_to_degrees(longi) #get longitude in degree decimal format

#convert raw NMEA string into degree decimal format   
def convert_to_degrees(raw_value):
decimal_value = raw_value/100.00
degrees = int(decimal_value)
mm_mmmm = (decimal_value - int(decimal_value))/0.6
position = degrees + mm_mmmm
position = "%.4f" %(position)
return position

gpgga_info = "$GPGGA,"
ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0")              #Open port with baud rate
GPGGA_buffer = 0
NMEA_buff = 0
lat_in_degrees = 0
long_in_degrees = 0

try:
while True:
    received_data = (str)(ser.readline())                   #read NMEA string    received
    GPGGA_data_available = received_data.find(gpgga_info)   #check for NMEA GPGGA string                 
    if (GPGGA_data_available>0):
        GPGGA_buffer = received_data.split("$GPGGA,",1)[1]  #store data coming after "$GPGGA," string 
        NMEA_buff = (GPGGA_buffer.split(','))               #store comma separated data in buffer
        GPS_Info()                                          #get time, latitude, longitude

        print("lat in degrees:", lat_in_degrees," long in degree: ", long_in_degrees, '\n')
        map_link = 'http://maps.google.com/?q=' + lat_in_degrees + ',' + long_in_degrees    #create link to plot location on Google map
        print("<<<<<<<<press ctrl+c to plot location on google maps>>>>>>\n")               #press ctrl+c to plot on map and exit 
        print("------------------------------------------------------------\n")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
webbrowser.open(map_link)        #open current position information in google map
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: look into http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: You need to setup a web server, using python framework such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), and then you need to run some client side Javascript to request for the data from the server, and plot it on google map using GoogleMap API. I have a [blog post](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/03/how-to-plot-cycling-route-using-google-maps-api-and-flask-web-framework/) on how to plot GPS data on Google Map, and another [blog post](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/) on how to serve data from devices through web server(not using flask though).